# getView() not being called on notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, onresume

Here's my problem: I have an app that has an activity with a listview inside it. This activity is recursive, when you click on an item on the list it takes you to the same activity with different items in the listview. A lot of the code is within the ArrayAdaptor for the listview.

When moving forward through the activities the new ones call getView() when creating the listview rows. But when stepping back (pressing back closing the current instance of the activity and moving back to the previous one) these already existent activities don't call getView() so my rows don't get updated.

So I need , `onResume`, to call getView for the rows. I've tried adding `notifyDataSetChanged()`,`requestLayout()` and `invalidate()` on onResume, doesn't work. getView just doesn't get called.

I've searched for answers to my problem, did not find any. I'm sure there are a million ways to improve my app if I re-write it from the ground up, that's not gonna happen any time soon. I just have a few days to finish this, I'm quite desperate. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried set adapter again in `onResume`?

Comment: Have you made sure that you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the correct instance of the adapter (i.e. the one attached to the listview)?
If during your lifecycle you re-instantiated the adapter without attaching it to the ListView, that can result in such annoying bugs.

Comment: @aim, thank you for your reply. I have tried that, something strange happens when I set the adapter again in `onResume`. The list is updated for an instant then reverts to its old form. I don't know why. Also when I try to change a value from the listview (by using a `startActivityForResult`) I get a nullpointerexeption.

Comment: @Patrick, thanks for the input. I use `((ArrayAdapter<MobileEvent>) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: If it reverts you can check who did this with debug. And if it fall with NPE please post code and stacktrace.

Comment: After some further testing it seems that getView() gets called when an instance of the activity is created and just before that instance is closed. So let's say we have 5 steps. When I go from step 3->4, 4getView is called, go 4->5, 5getView is called. Go 5->4 5getView is called again. 4->3, 4getView is NOT called. I've never been so confused.

Comment: Even FURTHER testing turns out that when moving back from 5->4 the    `onResume`  `notifyDataSetChanged();` get's called before the `getView()`. So one could say that getView() is being called correctly but on the wrong instance of the adaptor, just like @Patrick said. I will investigate further and post the answer here.

Comment: I'm ashamed to write this, but I found out yesterday what the problem was. Apparently my listView item got set to static when I implemented it into a static method. Everything seemed to work fine so I didn't know what a mistake I've made. Thank you for your input and I'm really sorry I wasted your time.